# uploading files to hadoop hdfs?

Tags: hadoop

Hello everyone i m new in using hadoop it is my college work so i am doing some research i have installed hadoop-2.7.3 and i m unable to find tha path where should i upload a file to check it over hadoop localhost?

this picture shows the folder made for datanodes and name nodes

inside hadoop_store

[image]

inside hdfs folder

Can anyone tell me what link i should give here.
[image]

any help will be appreciated
looking for help

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly copy the file.You should use the command line to upload files to hdfs.

This command will put 1.txt to root of hdfs.

```
 hadoop fs -put /home/hduser/1.txt /
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy file from local system to the hdfs you can use the following command.

**hdfs fs -put your_local_file_path /**

Once you are done copying, the file can be seen at (default)
http://localhost:50070/explorer.html#/

The uploaded file will can be viewed from the list.